# File size in Python server

Tags: python, ruby, client, size

We have server on Python and client + web service on Ruby. That works only if file from URL is less than 800 k. It seems like "socket.puts data" in a client works, but "output = socket.gets" - not. I think problem is in a Python part. For big files tests run "Connection reset by peer". Is it buffer size variable by default somewhere in a Python?

Comment: This post lacks details and is exceptionally vague. Source snippets would be much more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Could you add a little more information and code to your example?

Are you thinking about sock.recv_into() which takes a buffer and buffer size as arguments?  Alternately, are you hitting a timeout issue by failing to have a keepalive on the Ruby side?

Guessing in advance of knowledge.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Finally I did it by using loops and getting chunks both on the Ruby and the Python sides. That works.
Ruby:
<code>
    output = ""
    while !socket.eof? do
      output = output + socket.read(1024)
    end
</code>
Python:
<code>
def handle(self):
    total_data = []
    while 1:
          data = self.request.recv(1024)
          if len(data) < 1024:
              total_data.append(data)
              break
          total_data.append(data)
    t_data = ''.join(total_data)
</code>